# Grabbing Information from a Remote MP3 File

Tags: php, mysql, curl, mp3, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract MP3 ID3 Tag information from any remotely hosted mp3 file via PHP.
I've tried several times with fread and fseek to grab the last 128bytes of the file and extract the tag information...but had no success.

Here's and example of what I want to do:
http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/read-remote-mp3-avi-file-id3-information.html

Any tips or code snippets would be appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you show some code? Also note that the HTTP protocol doesn't support seeking, you will likely end up downloading the entire resource

Comment: Hey I don't have remote access to my home computer at the moment, I'll provide some code when i get home later tonight :) well i'm trying to download the last 128bytes of the mp3 file...which is where the tag info should be stored. I would rather download the last kilobyte of the file (i already know the filesize in bytes) than the whole thing...this isn't for just 1 mp3 file, it's for 17,000 links in a database of mine :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTTP you'd download a *range* of data from the resource. You can pick an arbitrary range and it can even consist of multiple parts like "X-Y" or "X-Y,A-B" etc.

Servers however don't always support that and then you'll be served the full file instead.

When using something like curl, you can use its CURLOPT_RANGE option (or the command line tool's -r).